# Function createEvent returning null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've been writing a code so I could automate creating events on my teammates calendars. For that, I've created a form with basic information, dropped that into a spreadsheet (so we could do others things with those logs) and wrote the code so it could automatically create events on the appropriate calendars based on the answers for the form.

I've encountered many issues (and it is a pretty basic code) but I'm new to coding and I'm very much still in a error-based learning pattern.

I've incurred in an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null at AutCal(Código:26:13)`, but I solved it by checking and renaming the sheet via code.

I've tested every var, logged their values so I'd know exactly what they were, wrote the loop nest and saved it. Here is what the code looks like:

```
function AutCalTESTE() {

  var row = 2;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Caledário (input) - Mirror');
  var marcado = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 10).getValue();
  var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var eventCall = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
  var STime = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  var ETime = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue();

  while (calendarID!=''){
  while(marcado!=''){
  eventCall.createEvent('Painel',STime,ETime);
  marcado.setValue('OK');
  row++
  };
};
}
```

Right now, the issue I cannot solve is that every time I'm debugging the code, it returns the same error, but with the method `.createEvent()`, saying that it cannot read property at null.

I'm a little lost, so any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

```
// make sure this is the same value as the Calendar ID you want
var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
//add some logging
Logger.log(calendarID)

//make sure this doesn't return null, if the calendar ID is wrong it will
var eventCall = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
Logger.log(eventCall)
```

If your calendarId is incorrect you will have an eventCall == null.

Which is why you are getting your error, trying to call a property of null.

Your calendar ID is available in the Calendar app, under Settings, and then under your specific calendar settings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @blrzzzt, but that does not seem to be the issue. When I run the code out of the loop it works fine, and every line of code works perfectly on it's own, but when I put it all together it gives me that error. I also tried inscribing the var inside the loop and change the code altogether, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: I just fixed the the issue I've been having, so the problem was actually the organization and syntax usage of my code (specifically the vars).

Here is how it goes:

```
function AutCalTESTE(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('X');
var ref = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 12).getValue();
var row = ref;
var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();

while (calendarID != ""){
var description = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue();
var marcado = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 10).getValue();
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID).createEventFromDescription(description);
spreadsheet.getRange(row, 10).setValue('OK');
row++
spreadsheet.getRange(1, 12).setValue(row);
var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();

};
};
```